# How to change the textcolor of tabs in android and background of tab in android with viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I am newbie to android and have prepared a demo for swipable tabs using viewpager and have prepared it successfully,Now i want to change the text color of tab and also selection,Please help me to sort it out,
**style.xml**

```
    <style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/radio_selected</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TabSpecialTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Modify the text color -->
    <style name="TabStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textColor">#F70000</item>
    </style>


    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>


</resources>
```

**main_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />
```

**mainListing.java**

```
public class MainListingActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager Tab;
    TabsPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listing);

        TabAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F05423")));

                    }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                        FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                        FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }};
        //Add New Tab
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("All").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Gents").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Ladies").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Kids").setTabListener(tabListener));


    }

    //change tab color..
    public void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {

        for (int i = 0; i < tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
            tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")); //unselected

        if (tabhost.getCurrentTab() == 0) {
            tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F05423"));
            //1st tab selected
        } else {
            tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F05423"));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="TabSpecialTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Modify the text color -->
<style name="TabStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
  <item name="android:textColor">#F70000</item>
</style>>
```

Comment: hy..ku6 bhi change nai hua ..:(

Comment: ye jo tumne niche method bnya hai set tab color isme color to set kiye h already

Comment: mene style bhi add kri for better understanding

Comment: par use call nai kraya na...kidhar call krau..mene to viewpager lia he..tabhost nai

Comment: yar bhai tu apni email id de me teko latest code bhejta hu vo bhut easy hai toolbar k sath tabs layout jese whats app ki layout h na same wesi h

Comment: Hi. please use English so it would be helpful for other Users.

Comment: thik he...me de rha hu

Comment: jigar.makwana@sterlite.com

Comment: ok me zip file bhejta hu tu extract kar ke import kar lena direct thik hai

Comment: Hy bro..mene copy kra but "TabLayout" not resolve aa rha he

Comment: kha pe a ra ye error rebuild krke dekh ek bar

Comment: vo error solve ki..ab run kia to  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. ye error aa gya he

Comment: ek bar rebuild krke dekh or ni to AppCombatActivity ki jgh FragmentActivity

Comment: likh ke dekh le